# Chrome Bookmarklet Works When Clicked, But Not When "Launched": Why?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarklet

I have a bookmarklet that fills in a form for me, and it works great when I click on it in my bookmarks toolbar.

However, when I hit `CTRL + L` (the "launch" shortcut, which takes you to the URL bar) and type in the bookmarklet's name (and hit `ENTER`), it fails to work.  In the console there's an error about "Unable to find element" (presumably the form element it's trying to fill in).

Can anyone explain why the bookmarklet would work, and be able to access the form, in my bookmarks toolbar, but not when I "launch" it from the URL bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. A bookmarklet (JavaScript code) runs on the existing page clicked (so the code to fill the form runs on the open tab of the form), so you can't open the bookmarklet by itself
2. <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> is not ***Launch***, it's **Jump to the address bar** and don't do anything, so it's just like clicking into the address bar, not sure why you think that should do something
3. You enter the bookmarklet **name** into the address bar? If something you need to paste the whole code into the address bar (and **after pasting** you need to go to the beginning of it and add `javascript:` before the code)

---

If you want to be able to easily run the bookmarklet with a keyboard shortcut, you'll need something more.

You can set up something like this with a Chrome Extension like **[Shortkeys (Custom Keyboard Shortcuts)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shortkeys-custom-keyboard/logpjaacgmcbpdkdchjiaagddngobkck/related)**, it allows you to set up a shortcut to trigger a bookmark that you have (see some info on it in this guide https://www.groovypost.com/howto/add-shortcut-keys-chrome-bookmarks/, something like this:
[image]

Comment: That's great ... if I want to copy paste the code for the bookmarklet every time (which is way more work than just clicking it).  But I'm trying to figure out how to trigger the bookmarklet from the keyboard, and since Chrome doesn't have bookmark keyboard shortcuts, that means using whatever `CTRL + L` is.

Comment: But CTRL+L doesn't have anything to do with what we're talking about... so TBH you should clarify in the Q what the goal is. I'm adding to my answer on how to set up a shortcut for a bookmarklet

Comment: Shortkeys is a great suggestion, but I'm still trying to understand the original thing I asked about.  Again, I'm trying to trigger a bookmarklet (without an extension), using my keyboard, in Chrome.  I can trigger the exact same bookmarklet just fine by clicking on it: it works great!  All I want to understand (ie. all I need to accept an answer) is an explanation of why it *doesn't* work when I run it via `CTRL + L`, and whether there's any sort of workaround to make it work (*besides* pasting the bookmark's contents in every time, which is a "cure worse than the illness").

Comment: Why? Because, other than you mistakenly thought, CTRL + L has nothing to do with "running"/"launching" stuff, and bookmarks cannot be called (in the address bar, which expects a website address) using their name.

Comment: So then why, when I press `CTRL + L` and type the first few characters of my bookmark's name, does it appear? And then, when I hit `ENTER`, why does it run it? (It runs with an error, but it does run.)  Also, I didn't just imagine this idea: it was specifically suggested on other websites as a way to run a bookmark from the keyboard.

Comment: Link to those other websites so we'll be able to discuss what they say. Also, what happens when you "run" it and it has an error, does it stay on the old webpage? A screenshot of how you try it and the code (generic) you're using in the bookmarklet might also be helpful to figure it out.

Comment: Good suggestion ... but the problem fixed itself (see below).  Thanks for your assistance though!

Comment: `CTRL + L` also works for launching a bookmark for me, if you type the name of the bookmark it appears in the search results, then use the arrow keys to select it and press enter to open/run the bookmark/bookmarklet (in Chrome and Brave browsers)

Answer (score 0):

After @Yisroel Tech suggested I take a screenshot I went back to the web page and ... `CTRL + L` (seemingly magically) now works.

I'm not sure what fixed it, but I did restart my computer (which meant also restarting my browser), so if anyone else has trouble running a bookmarklet with `CTRL + L` I'd recommend trying that first.